# If a sequence of integers converges, is its limit an integer?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let ${a_{n}}$ be a convergent sequence in $\mathbb Z$. Is it true that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{a_{n}}\in \mathbb Z$?

#### Remark

This is false if $\mathbb Z$ is replaced by $\mathbb Q$, because then we can have, for example,
$$1,1.4,1.41,1.414,1.4142, 1.41421 \dots \to \sqrt{2}  $$

Comment: what is the definition of limit and meaning of convergence?

Comment: Think about $a_n=n$.

Comment: Raskolnikov seems to be adopting the convention that if the limit of a sequence is infinite then we can say it converges (in the wide sense), though in many parts that would be called "divergence" or simply "the limit doesn't exist" (in a finite way). If the OP meant the former then Raskolnikov's comment is a counterexample, but if the OP meant the latter then Thomas and Tetori's answers wrap the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. If $a_n \to L$ as $n\to\infty$, there exists $N$ such that

$$n>N \implies |a_n-L|<1/4.$$

and if $m,n>N$, we get
$$|a_m-a_n|\le |a_m-L| +|a_n-L| <1/2$$

Since $a_m, a_n$ is integer, they have same value. So $ \left< a_n\right>$ is constant if $n>N$.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$, then $\mathbb{Z}$ is a closed set, so the limit of any sequence in $\mathbb{Z}$, which is an accumulation point of $\mathbb{Z}$, must be in $\mathbb{Z}$ because a closed set contains all of it's accumulation points.